# How can I can I customize Xamarin.Forms app based on screen width or orientation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that uses Xamarin.Forms.  I would like to use a different grid layout for a horizontal (or wide screen tablet vertical).  I know how to use a view model and how to have two grids with one visible and the other not visible.

But how can I from within the application, determine some basic dimensions, type of divide or orientation?

Comment: How-tos are off topic. And the official book is free, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Xamarin.Essentials, which will enable you to get all those properties (orientation, rotation, density, width, and height)

To install Nuget package Xamarin.Essentials, start by ticking the checkbox: Include prerelease.

Add to code-behind:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

After that..

```
var metrics = DeviceDisplay.ScreenMetrics;
// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = metrics.Orientation;
// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = metrics.Rotation;
// Width (in pixels)
var width = metrics.Width;
// Height (in pixels)
var height = metrics.Height;
// Screen density
var density = metrics.Density;
```

From what I can tell Height gives you the available height of the page, that is the after the height of any menu on top is subtracted.

More information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms